# Evaluate $|\int_{-9}^9[ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})]|$

Tags: integration

Evaluate $|\int_{-9}^9[ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})]|$, where |.|represent absolute value & [.] represent greatest integer function.

As the f(x) lies in the [.] we cannot do substitution, the function is symmetry about y=x and absolue bracket makes the function of the type $2\int_{0}^9[ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})]$ beyond this i am not able to solve it.

Comment: The absolute bracket is outside the integral. That means, we don't have to take absolute value of the function but of the final value after the limits are been put. Also, notice that $ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}) $ is odd function.

Comment: Try the substitution $x=\sinh\theta$...

Answer (score 1):

Does [ ] mean a ceiling function?

Anyway, if $f = \ln (x + \sqrt{1+x^2})$, then its floor (or ceiling) is a piecewise constant function. $f$ only crosses a few integers when $x\in (0,9)$. Can you find those?

Comment: Please try to give hints in the comments first. And [ ] is not ceiling function but floor function (also called GIF).

Comment: (+1) This seems like a very fair hint.

Comment: On the other hand, perhaps $[\ ]$ is just a bracket.

Comment: I am getting the answer 9 by putting it in desmoa.com but not able to proof it mathematically